# Can't find Google Play Services in components in Xamarin Android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, xamarin-component

I am trying to add the Google Play Services component to my Xamarin application because I need to integrate google maps api into the application. When I try to search Google play services in components I can't find Google Play Services. I see other components such as Google Play services-ads or Google Play Services- App Indexing but no Google Play Services.

I installed the Google play services client in the sdk manager:

[image]

And the minimum api level that the app is targeting is level 19. Still I can't find Google Play Services. Here is a screenshot of the all the results:
[image]

**Edit**

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54499/google-play-services-v27-migration

According to the above website google play services-All does not exist anymore and now their are individual packages. So now I have to install Google Play Services-Maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NuGet to download [Google Play Services Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps/) to your project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps/

Or you can download the component from the [component store](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices-maps)

https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices-maps

The Google Play Services library was too large at one point and google decided to separate the concerns into a smaller packages for many reasons such as hitting 64K reference limit too fast even though you only used a small subset of the APIs for your application.

You can read an overview guide on this topic here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview